# Change the data of an array from C in Python

Tags: python, c, api, numpy, cython

My goal is to create an array in C, give it to a Cython/Python function which alters the data and gives it back to C and read the data from C. My program works just fine if I **don't** do anything to the array in python and just return it. However once I do absolutely anything inside that function my program breaks after the "After the function:"-print.

My current code looks like this:

test.pyx

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef public c_array_to_numpy(input):
    cdef int[:,::1] temp = input
    temp[2,0] = 13
    return input
```

main.c

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <ndarrayobject.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    import_array();

    int array1[2][3] = {{3, 7, 4}, {8, 5, 9}};

    int nd = 2;

    npy_intp const dims[2] = {2, 3};

    PyObject* new_array3 = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(nd, dims, NPY_INT32,(void*) array1);

    Py_INCREF(new_array3);
    Py_INCREF(new_array3);

    printf("Before the function:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%i ", array1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("After the function:\n");
    PyObject* changed = c_array_to_numpy(new_array3);
    int* data_changed = PyArray_DATA(changed);
    printf("%i", changed[2]);


    Sleep(3000);
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying, if `c_array_to_numpy` is defined as `cdef public c_array_to_numpy(input): return input`, it works?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But whenever I try to do anything to input within the function it breaks.

Comment: @Yeji Ha `PyObject* changed = c_array_to_numpy(input);`. Where does the `input` defined within the `C` code?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. I fixed it, it should read ```PyObject* changed = c_array_to_numpy(new_array3);``` Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: The c_array_to_numpy function returns a PyObject* (just took a look into the generated test.c file) - However I tried it with PyArrayObject* instead of PyObject* but it didn't work as well.